# Sharepoint Content Databases goes on "Error" status on "Content Databases" page in central administration

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

Our My Sites web application in our Sharepoint 2019 farm has 3 databases. Every hour, the database status of two of three databases goes into 'Error" status. We have to manually click on the database details and click 'OK' to bring the database online to show the status as 'Started' on the central administration page.

When we run the command as follows, we get the offline status.

```
PS c:\users\user> $db = Get-SPContentDatabase 'WSS_Content_MySites'
PS c:\users\user> $db.status
offline
```

Kindly advise as we cannot get any error captured in the error log or event viewer or any failed job log. Database is accessible and is in online status.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your SQL database backups? Are they failing?

Comment: SQL backups are fine, no errors at the DB level. When I edit the job "Some content databases are growing too large" and unselect "repair automatically", the issue is gone. The DB sizes are nowhere near 100 GB, so I am perplexed as to why this job tries to repair them in the first place.

Comment: Is SQL Server taking the DB offline? Is there enough storage space on the server?

Comment: Did you solved your problem?
I have the same

Comment: Yes, we did, via a workaround. The rule "Some content databases are growing too large" was putting the datbases offline as the size was over 100GB. In our case, we didn't have the resources to move sites to another DB, so we disabled this job. Please refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/some-content-databases-are-growing-too-large